# How to advance the array base address using a function?

Tags: c, linux, pointers

i am trying writing a function that forwards the pointer by a specified size in bytes.

```
void
increment_ptr(void **_ptr, int size){
    *_ptr = (char *)(*_ptr) + size;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv){
    int arr[] = {11,20};
    printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
    increment_ptr((void **)&arr, sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

output i am getting is :

```
vm@vm:~$ ./a.out
11
15
```

I am expecting the output to be 11, and 20.

Can anybody pls help ?

Comment: second printf should print the second element of the array which is 20.

Comment: You expected `increment_ptr` to change `arr` a certain way; can you check that more directly?

Comment: I understand that it can be done directly, i have pasted the simplified version of what i am trying to do in my project. So, pls let it be this way ..

Comment: An array is not a pointer. You cannot increment an array.

Comment: @4386427 actually `arr` is an lvalue . For example you can take its address.

Answer (score 4):

`arr` is not an ordinary variable that you can change. It is not a pointer - its type is `int[2]`.

Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void
increment_ptr(void **_ptr, int size){
    *_ptr = (char *)(*_ptr) + size;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv){
    int arr[] = {11,20};
    int* arr1 = arr;

    printf("arr  is %p\n", (void*)arr);
    printf("arr1 is %p\n", (void*)arr1);
    printf("arr gives  %d\n", arr[0]);
    printf("arr1 gives %d\n", arr1[0]);

    increment_ptr((void **)&arr, sizeof(int));
    increment_ptr((void **)&arr1, sizeof(int));

    printf("arr  is %p\n", (void*)arr);
    printf("arr1 is %p\n", (void*)arr1);
    printf("arr gives  %d\n", arr[0]);
    printf("arr1 gives %d\n", arr1[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
arr  is 0xfff1d1b8
arr1 is 0xfff1d1b8
arr gives  11
arr1 gives 11
arr  is 0xfff1d1b8   // Notice arr isn't changed
arr1 is 0xfff1d1bc   // arr1 works as expected
arr gives  15
arr1 gives 20
```

In other words: You can't advance the base address of such an array

You might also find this code interesting:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int arr[2] = {11,20};
    printf("arr  is %p\n", (void*)arr);
    printf("arr  is %p\n", (void*)&arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
arr   is 0061FED8
&arr  is 0061FED8
```

Notice how printing `arr` as a pointer gives the same as printing `&arr`

So what happens in your code is that the number `11` (aka arr[0]) is read as a pointer (casted to char*), then add `4` (so you have `15`) which overwrites the current `11`. Note: This result indicates the pointers and `int`s are both 4 bytes on your system.

Comment: `arr` is an lvalue.  But that is irrelevant to the question

Comment: @M.M - Hmmm, ok, I may be wrong :-) But `++arr` will give `error: lvalue required as increment operand` when using gcc

Comment: It is a misleading message from gcc, it should say "modifiable lvalue required as increment operand".  An array is an lvalue but not a modifiable lvalue .

Comment: @M.M - I removed the part of the answer talking about `lvalue`. I guess I have to read up on `modifiable lvalue` versus `non-modifiable lvalue` :-) Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
int arr[2];
```

declares a memory space. So, when you acquire its address it returns you the base address of this memory space, which is identical to arr.

This is different to the case when you declare a pointer. A pointer is a variable that saves an address, but an array is just the memory space.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable (array or not), it has an address that is unchanged for the rest of that variable's lifetime.  It is not possible to move a variable to a new address.

Your code just causes undefined behaviour (strict aliasing violation - `*_ptr` uses an lvalue of type `void *` to access memory declared as `int`).